# PDFLib fails to create PDF file in pvf

Tags: visual-c++, pdflib

```
mpdf.create_pvf(card, mpImgBytes, mlen, L"");
int inDoc = mpdf.open_pdi_document(card, L"");
```

I am using pdflib version 9.3.

> open_pdi_document returns -1

> create_pvf creates an empty file of size 0.
> Any idea on what could be wrong?

I am running pdflib on Windows 10, using C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how relevant my answer is, but this could help someone.

> Installing ghostscript on my machine, resolved the error.

Comment: ok, then the hint (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74443860/2862406) checking the error reasons from open_pdi_document() was already helpful that it was not a valid input PDF.
PDFlib itself has no dependency on GhostScript, so your solution does not seem to fix a PDFlib problem, but another one in Worfklow.

Comment: Yes. I have marked your answer as useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you also retrieve the error reason in case of an error (`open_pdi_document()` returns -1) or work with the PDFlib errorpolicy "*exception*". Then you will get a first impression what the problem might be, then your code could looks like

```
        /* Open the input PDF */
        indoc = mpdf.open_pdi_document(card, L"");
        if (indoc == -1) {
            wcerr << L"Error: " << mpdf.get_errmsg() << endl;
            return 2;
        }
```

> create_pvf creates an empty file of size 0.

how did you identify that?

Comment: I get the message - "Error: '/pvf/cardimage/Dict_5_4Data' does not appear to be a PDF file". This file is of size zero at a local path on my machine.

Comment: Then you obviously pass an invalid input file. I would try the following steps: 
**save the data to a disk** and then try to open it with a PDF viewer. If that works, load this input file via PDI from disk.  

If you don't get anywhere with this, then I recommend that you perhaps contact [https://www.pdflib.com/licensing-support/opening-a-support-case/(PDFlib technical support) directly.